error massage when publishing app in google play store
I'm attempting to release an updated version of my Android application on the Google Play Store, but I've encountered an error. Below is a screenshot detailing the issue:
enter image description here
i don't understand this email

The screenshot clearly states that your account has been suspended for repeatedly violating the Developer Program Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement. For more information and assistance, please reach out to the Google support team.

Seems pretty self explanatory. Your app doesn't comply with Googles Developer Program Policies and the Developer Distribution Agreement, that's why they deactivated your account. I think your best option would be to contact their support and try to resolve this issue. If you update your app to comply with their policies they might reactivate your account.
